# How to use MultiAutoCompleteTextView with splitwise's TokenAutoComplete

Tags: android, eclipse, git, autocompletetextview

I find a git project that claims to be able to do MultiAutoCompleteTextView GMail style. But when I download the project and open it in eclipse as `android project from existing source` it does not work. What am I missing there? Has anyone successfully run the project?

Normally, a git project is something you can clone/download and run as is and then try to modify for your own devise. Is this one different?

https://github.com/splitwise/TokenAutoComplete

Answer (score 0):

Looks like AndroidStudio project (IntelliJIdea). It won't open in eclipse, but you could create a new eclipse project and use the code as source anyway.

Answer (score 0):

This is my project. We've been using it internally at Splitwise for a while and there are a number of other people using it as well. I've just been using Android Studio, so the whole project is based on the current best practices for that (using gradle for builds/AS friendly project structure). I don't use Eclipse and haven't had any pull requests to support Eclipse better, so we're bad on support for that.

That being said, you can grab a packaged jar file from the releases page (https://github.com/splitwise/TokenAutoComplete/releases) and add that to your project pretty easily.

The code is also just two files here: https://github.com/splitwise/TokenAutoComplete/tree/master/library/src/main/java/com/tokenautocomplete

You can probably just grab the TokenCompleteTextView.java file and edit the package structure to put it in your project directly if you want to mess with the code.

Comment: in splitwise's TokenAutoComplete if we set token limit to 20 and add 20 tokens, when the tokencompleteView loses focus it crashes